# Number of muffins baked

Tags: fractions, word-problem

Mr Ali baked some muffins. **(3/5)** of the muffins wee chocolate and the rest were vanilla. After she sold **(2/9)** of the chocolate muffins and **(1/2)** of the vanilla muffins, 230 muffins were left. How many chocolate muffins did Mrs Ali bake?

My work

Number of chocolate: C

Number of Vanilla: V

Total: T

---

C = **(3/5)** T

V = **(2/5)** T

This is the part where I'm not sure.

C (1 - **2/9**) + V (1 - **1/2**) = T - 230

or

C (1 - **2/9**) + V (1 - **1/2**) =  230

Comment: The second equation $C(1-\frac{2}{9}) + V(1-\frac{1}{2}) = 230$ is correct because there are $230$ left.